# Problem with PCB circuit

Tags: pcb, esp8266

I am attempting to build a WiFi controlled power outlet. Essentially all it's supposed to be is an ESP-12E that controls a relay. When I had breadboarded the circuit it worked fine, however after getting it manufactured on a PCB a problem occurred and I do not know how to fix it. Here are schematics and images.

[image: Schematic]

[image: PCB Design]

[image: Top View]

[image: Bottom View]

The problem I am having is that the current is barely flowing. I get a read of about 0.02 mAH flowing through the circuit. I can see that the LED turns on however it is extremely dim and barely noticable. If put my finger  across some of the connections on the bottom side of the board the LED goes bright and the ESP-12E LED blinks (meaning that it turned on), but this only happens if I do so in the "right" place. I figured this was a problem that had to do with poor connections but I looked over the entire circuit and found nothing of the sort. I would also like to point out that the schematic is slightly  outdated, and I am actually  using a  46µF capacitor instead of a  0.1µF capacitor.

Comment: What's powering it? Also, do you by 0.02 mAH mean 0.02 mA? -5V is shorted to ground too.

Comment: You should also have a 0.1uF ceramic capacitor connected across the Vcc and GND of the ESP-12E, along with the 47uF. Have you checked voltages throughout the circuit to make sure everything is getting power?

Comment: Post up to date and full circuit diagram.

Comment: C2 doesn't appear to have any traces connecting it.  None on the layout, at any rate.  Can't tell from the board itself.

Comment: Where are the caps for the voltage regulator?

Comment: @winny Forgot  to mention, my mistake. It is being powered by a power converter, linked here: 

https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01FA0KJFA/ref=oh_aui_search_detailpage?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @DerStrom8 Yes, voltage is flowing as it  should with 5v coming  in and 3.3v coming out. The odd  part is that there is no current.

Comment: If you have to have a new board made, consider leaving more space around the AC connections.  I think you have things (T1 and D1 and associated traces) too close to the AC connections.  There are standards for the spacing at various voltages.  My (uncalibrated) eyeball measurement says "too close." I could well be wrong, but it can't hurt to double check things.

Comment: I also don't see a Vcc connection to the LEDs. Routing is pretty sad in general. ALso I am assuming there is a ground fill here... you need to show that graphic too.

Comment: If you have a scope, use it to check the output of the regulator.  It could be oscillating, and have an average of 3.3VDC. Your multimeter would show good voltage but the ESP12 wouldn't be able to operate.

Comment: @JRE Clear creepage violation!

Comment: "...only happens if I do so in the "right" place" - which place is that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott If I push down on the esp module, on the side where the GND is, the LED brightens (more current flowing). If  I touch across the resistor closest to the capacitor the LED is at  maximum brightness and is (for some odd reason) green instead of white.

Comment: Sounds like bad connections between the module and pcb.

Comment: To experienced readers, your +5V and -5V labels on the power input imply a bipolar supply totalling 10 Volts.  To make it clear that you have a single 5 Volt supply, you could show a single "5V label, with "+" and "-" on the appropriate terminals, or "+5V" on one terminal, and "Gnd" on the other.

Comment: are all the vias (holes) plated through?

Answer (score 3):

I see some pins not terminated properly. I have been using this schematic for a while now without seeing any failure in almost a thousand boards produced:

[image: ESP diagram]

Besides this, I'd suggest some minor routing changes. For ex - You are routing this DC line too close to high voltage ac line:

[image: routing]

You can rearrange the components to get a better isolation between ac and DC.

Another issue that I see is a bad implementation of GND plane:

[image: gnd plane]

You should make the ground pour in DC region only.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull the reset pin High and Chip enable pin high using maybe 10K resistors for it to work, look at the datasheet. Fix your symbol so we can see correct pin names and numbers. Looks like you're using Kicad, run a DRC on your schematic and board to make sure everything is connected. Your T1 looks to have wrong foot print as well, can't tell without pin numbers on layout. You've got an RGB LED? but only 1 current limiting resistor?

Clean up your schematic, you've been advised to do this numerous times, but you have not done so, how do you expect someone to help you when you don't try to help yourself? for example, what's the value of R2? 2-Million Ohms? or 7-Million Ohms?

Comment: R2 is just the identifier for the resistor, it's what you're supposed to do so other people reading the schematic can easily refer to different resistors.

I only have 1 current limiting resistor because the output voltage on the ESP is 3.3v, which is safe for G  and B, but no R.